# Is there a standard for flash memory's real capacity?

Tags: capacity, flash-memory, usb-flash-drive

For example...
16GB USB flash drive's real capacity is almost 14.8~15.4 GiB.

these are different by each manufaturers or models.

In this situation....
How can I expect real **minimum capacity?**(GiB or Sectors)

Is there a standard? or de facto?

Comment: ps. I know 'LBA1-03' standard of IDEMA. But that is for only SSD/HDD, not USB flash drive / sdhc

Comment: Is this help full ?? https://www.quora.com/Why-isnt-the-entire-space-of-a-pen-drive-and-memory-card-available-for-storage

Answer (score 0):

Back in the days, the size for hard-drives were always in [gibibytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibibyte) (1000 mibibytes) instead of gigabytes. That accounts for 7,4% size difference when comparing a gigabyte with a gibibyte.